# Unable to set text using Quill.JS setText Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, quill

I am using [quill rich text editor](https://quilljs.com/) to generate rich text text area in html. But problem is that i was not able to set any text to rich text using quill `setText` method. Anyone can advice me whats wrong i am doing here? why `setText` is not working?

Html:

```
   <link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Description">Article:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="Article" rows="6"></textarea>
   </div>
```

Quill script:

```
<script>
var quill = new Quill('#Article', {
    theme: 'snow',
    
});
quill.setText('Hello\n');

</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the official documentation of Quill you do not need to use `textArea` HTML element.

Just use `div` and quill will work as a text editor on that.

When `textarea` is used with Quill it conflict with HTML default behavior and `quill`.

You can read more about it [here](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/) and here is what it says.

> **Note** by supplying your own HTML element, Quill searches for particular input elements, *but your own inputs* that have nothing to do with Quill can still be added and styled and coexist.

```js
var quill = new Quill('#Article', {
  theme: 'snow'
});

quill.setText('Hello World\n');
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.3.6/quill.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="Description">Article:</label>
  <div class="form-control" id="Article" rows="6"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

check your browser console to confirm that quill scripts are working correctly